# How to insert a text box with controllable margin

Tags: spacing, boxes

I want to insert a text box with controllable margin. Specially, how to format the following text as the following Figure? And how to set the space? Currently, I use

```
\noindent\fbox{
    \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \textbf{Finding 3:} the text  \\
        \textbf{Implication:} the text 
    }
}
```

but the space is almost 0.

Text:

Most of row-level failures are due to exceptional data. Since the exceptional data are unforeseeable, programmers could proactively write exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge to help reduce failures, sharing the similar philosophy with the defensive programming.

Finding 3: Row-level failures are prevalent (62.0%). Most of them are caused by exceptional data. Programmers cannot know all of exceptional data in advance. Implication: Proactively writing exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge could help reduce row-level failures.

How to fix the failures is closely related to the reasons that cause the failures. For most failure categories, there exist fix patterns. Fixes under these patterns are very small in terms of LOC. In Sample Set A, 95.0% fixes are within 10 LOC and 87.0% fixes are within 5 LOC; the average size of fixes is 3.5 LOC. In addition, fix patterns such as row filtering, nullity checking, and resources import, usually do not involve program semantics. Hence, based on these patterns, it is possible to automatically generate some fix suggestions to help programmers fix corresponding defects.

[image]

Comment: \fboxsep=1em (for example)  Default is 3pt.  Also, your current code adds a space between the start of the \fbox and the \parbox.  You can remove it using \fbox{% or increase it using \fbox{\hspace{1em} for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `framed` package. The spacing between frame and text inside is controlled by the `FrameSep` length. `\FrameOuterSep` is the vertical spacing between surrounding text and frame. Of course the frame and the background can be coloured, its thickness can be changed (it is the `FrameRule` length) and, most of all, it can break across pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\FrameSep{0.5em}
\setlength\OuterFrameSep{\partopsep}
\begin{document}

Most of \emph{row-level} failures are due to exceptional data. Since the exceptional data are unforeseeable, programmers could proactively write exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge to help reduce failures, sharing the similar philosophy with the defensive programming.

\begin{framed}\noindent
  \textbf{Finding 3:} Row-level failures are prevalent (62.0\,\%). Most of them are caused by exceptional data. Programmers cannot know all of exceptional data in advance. \\
  \textbf{Implication:} Proactively writing exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge could help reduce row-level failures.
\end{framed}

How to fix the failures is closely related to the reasons that cause the failures. For most failure categories, there exist fix patterns. Fixes under these patterns are very small in terms of LOC. In Sample Set A, 95.0\,\% fixes are within 10 LOC and 87.0\,\% fixes are within 5 LOC; the average size of fixes is 3.5 LOC. In addition, fix patterns such as row filtering, nullity checking, and resources import, usually do not involve program semantics. Hence, based on these patterns, it is possible to automatically generate some fix suggestions to help programmers fix corresponding defects.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `tcolorbox` solution with the margin parameters controlled by `left` and `boxsep` or `right` options.

It's possible to change the margins later on with specification as optional argument to the environment `somebox`.

I've left the `\%` in the second box on purpose, to show the better spacing in with `siunitx` (first example)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{siunitx}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{somebox}[1][]{arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=1pt,boxsep=1pt,boxrule=1pt,width=\columnwidth,right=1pt,#1}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


Most of \emph{row-level} failures are due to exceptional data. Since the exceptional data are unforeseeable, programmers could proactively write exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge to help reduce failures, sharing the similar philosophy with the defensive programming.
\begin{somebox}
\textbf{Finding 3:} Row-level failures are prevalent (\SI{62.0}{\percent}). Most of them are caused by exceptional data. Programmers cannot know all of exceptional data in advance. 

\textbf{Implication:} Proactively writing exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge could help reduce row-level failures.the text 
\end{somebox}

\begin{somebox}[left=5pt]
  \textbf{Finding 3:} Row-level failures are prevalent (62.0\%). Most of them are caused by exceptional data. Programmers cannot know all of exceptional data in advance. 

  \textbf{Implication:} Proactively writing exceptional-data-handling code with domain knowledge could help reduce row-level failures.the text 

\end{somebox}


\end{document}
```

[image]